# Pipe file containing list of images to sxiv and reflect changes immediadly

Tags: command-line, pipe, cat, watch

Suppose I have a file `images.txt` which contains for example

```
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
image3.jpg
```

Then I pipe the `images.txt` to `sxiv` and  I want that the thumbnail view reflects the changes immediately. I tried this one:

`watch -n 0.1 'cat images.txt | sxiv -i -t'`

But if I change the `images.txt` and save it (for example by adding or removing an image-filename), the thumbnail view in sxiv doesn't update.

I guess that there is something wrong with my pipe construction. What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Maybe add a `-p` to tell sxiv not to cache the images? It would make a lot more sense to only run sxiv when something changes rather than 10 times a second.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that I have to close the `sxiv` window to update the changes in the `images.txt` file (then immediately a new window pops up with the updated content) if I use my pipe construct, but that's not exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Your existing construction will attempt to run `cat images.txt | sxiv -i -t` every tenth of a second.  If `sxiv` takes longer than that to do whatever it does, things could get quite messy.  You might be better off looking at a hash of a checksum of all of the images:

```
$ md5sum *.jpg | md5sum
4a009e73fb133d2d103dd2e65ef8c605  -
```

This takes a hash of all of the `.jpg` files, and makes a hash of *that*.  This means that the sur-checksum will change if any of the images are changes, as well as if any are added or removed.

So we can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
old_checksum="$(md5sum *.jpg | md5sum)"
while /bin/true; do
    new_checksum="$(md5sum *.jpg | md5sum)"
    if [[ "$new_checksum" != "$old_checksum" ]]; then
        old_checksum="$new_checksum"
        find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*.jpg -print0 | xargs -0 sxiv -i -t
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Anytime anything changes, take a note of the new checksum, and re-run `sxiv`.

If you still want to keep your catalog of `.jpg` files in `images.txt`, this can be easily modified to use the contents of that file for creating the checksum and for providing arguments to `xargs` in lieu of `find`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes indeed I want to keep the "catalog" in "images.txt". The file will be auto updated in another step. How would your solution look like using "images.txt"? Just calculate the md5sum of images.txt and replace the find command with cat images.txt?

Comment: I think you need a `killall sxiv` before the `find` line to prevent that a new instance of sxiv is started and also a `&` after `-t`?

Comment: I don't use a `&` to ensure that only one instance of `find` and therefore only one instance of `sxiv` is ever running at a time, which means a `kill` should not be needed.